# Memory warning and crashing app - can't find source of issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, instruments, memory-warning

My app is constantly crashing after receiving many memory warnings. It is almost thirty thousand lines of code long so it is not easy to track the problem. I have run it through instruments and there are up to 30MB of live bytes at some stages, which should not be too much of an issue as far as I am aware. The memory leaks are extremely minimal, so they can not be the problem. The app tends to crash after playing it for long periods of time. Nothing in instruments has helped me to track the source of the memory warnings I am constantly receiving. Is there any other possible way to do this? It is very important that this doesn't happen for obvious reasons. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the VM Tracking tool to see how much dirty memory is associated with your app. It's almost certainly leaks that appear very small because the tracking structures in your app's memory space are small, but they're associated with media objects in another memory space (e.g., pictures being backed by large render buffers in the render server, audio/video files being backed by buffers in mediaserverd and launchpad, etc). The VM Tracker tool will show you the real picture of your app's memory usage. Those "tiny" leaks may not be tiny at all.

Comment: Have you tried Analyze Build Product -> Analyze ? surely show some lines with memory leakage...

Comment: @JasonCoco apparently 76% of the resident memory is dirty. I am not very familiar with VM Tracker, but I assume this means I have alot of leaks and unused memory. The next step would be to figure out exactly what id causing this, and this is where I am now stuck.

Comment: @Keithbunts Analysis did not reveal anything significant

Comment: About dirty memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176074/what-do-dirty-and-resident-mean-in-relation-to-virtual-memory

Comment: You should also take some time and watch the latest WWDC videos about instruments. They spend some time explaining the VM tracker and how to find the causes of the dirty memory. In my experience, it's often leaked or abandoned references to media that is the biggest offender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, 30MB of live bytes are not that little memory, in my experience. IMO, it is ok to consume up to large amounts of memory but only for a very short time, then go back to safer levels of memory occupation (which if you want to address iPad1 should be between 10 and 15/20 MB).

I think this is the case for "abandoned memory", i.e., memory which is allocated and, although it could be freed, is never (or too late).

Have a look at [this post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/08/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html) to learn about snapshot memory analysis, which could help in your case.

Of course there is also a chance that your app **does** need that much memory (e.g., because of some large resources it handles), and in this case the path forward would be trying to reduce required memory (and this highly depends on the kind of data your app manages. If it is a game, e.g., you could use an RGB565 format instead of RGBA8888 for your artworks).

Besides, if Instruments allows you to pin down a certain number of cases where the memory consumption goes up, you could work on those to remove all leaks you have, or remove abandoned memory, or optimize your app memory consumption requirements.

Comment: Thanks alot, this has helped me greatly. It seems that I have alot of unused memory, now the only issue I have is that I don't know exactly WHAT is causing this to happen. I will first try to reduce memory consumption by changing artwork and the likes, and then use instruments to track the exact issues if it is needed.